# how to show json array jquery in table

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel

how to showing data url in table
i try with my json

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("coba.json",function (data) {
            var coba = '';
            $.each(data,function (key,value) {
                coba += '<tr>';
                coba += '<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
                coba += '<td>'+value.contact_first_name+'</td>';
                coba += '<td>'+value.contact_last_name+'</td>';
                coba += '<td>'+value.contact_gender+'</td>';
                coba += '</tr>';
            });
            $('#ayam').append(coba);
        });
    });
</script>
```

my json code
    https://pastebin.com/nxUkJqv5

Comment: whats your error?

Comment: data not show ... im use url  form api

Comment: you missed json.parse(data) for your data

Comment: @AhmedSunny  no,`$.getJSON` do it automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `data.data` inside `$.each` And code will work

Hard-coded working snippet:-https://jsfiddle.net/pqgo6rxa/

Note:- It's because `data` is the index which have all values that you want to append to table.

Comment: @Nanda  i don't know laravel. Sorry. You can ask new question for requirement